# AngularJS: filter applies through property which is not mentioned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a below code

**angularDemo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body >
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);
demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
              {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/view1.html'          
              })
        .when('/view2',
              {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/view2.html'
              })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
demoApp.controller('SimpleController',function($scope){

$scope.customers = [{name:'Pranav', city:'Pune'},{name:'Yogi', city:'Banglore'},{name:'Ashish', city:'Malad'},{name:'Ritesh', city:'bangkok'}];

});
</script>
<div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Partials/view1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
<title>View 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
<input ng-model='name1' type='text'>
<p>{{name1}}, How is it going?</p>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name1 | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

**Partials/view2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
<title>View 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
<input ng-model='city' type='text'>
<p>{{city}}, Its a Beautifull place to be.</p>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:city | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now whenever I type any city-name in input to filter the list in view1, then it gets filtered, but as per the functionality it should only filter by name of customer and vice versa is also happening in view2.html

Could some help me understanding how is this filter proeprty working in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined customer property, so the filter applies to all customer properties.
What you need to do is to define customer properties for each filter

```
 <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:{name:name1} | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
```

and

```
 <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:{city:city} | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
```

[AngularJS official docs on filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

Comment: Your solution is valid but I just reffered the manual where I cam e to know that the way I have applied the filter, will react the way it is acting right now my code, hence It has to be specific using `.$` symbol

Answer (score 1):

you can define what should be filtered based on your object structure:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:{city:name1} | orderBy:'city'">
```

UPDATE:

this is your data model:

```
$scope.customers = [{name:'Pranav', city:'Pune'},{name:'Yogi', city:'Banglore'},{name:'Ashish', city:'Malad'},{name:'Ritesh', city:'bangkok'}];
```

in view1:

```
<input ng-model='name1' type='text'>
<p>{{name1}}, How is it going?</p>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:{name:name1}| orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>
```

in view2:

```
<input ng-model='city1' type='text'>
<p>{{city}}, Its a Beautifull place to be.</p>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:{city:city1} | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
</ul>
```

Basically, you are telling filter function that filter the array of customer objects by the city property which has value of city1, and for view2 the same for name.

this should do what you need.

You can read about filters: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

Comment: I am not sure whether you understtod the problem, Sir, the point is view1 should search with only name and view 2 should search with only city

Comment: Thats Elobrative Thanks